# Simple dependency tree diagram generator

Tags: data-structures, reporting

I have a need to produce a simple dependency tree diagram. The input data would be in the following simple format:

```
ITEM_NAME   DEPENDENCY
----------------------------
ITEM_101    ITEM_75
ITEM_102    ITEM_77
ITEM_102    ITEM_61
ITEM_102    ITEM_11
```

This means that ITEM_101 depends on ITEM_75 and ITEM_102 depends on items ITEM_77, ITEM_61 and ITEM_11.  So the diagram would have items ITEM_77, ITEM_61 and ITEM_11 in one vertical level and ITEM_102 would be below it with a line connecting each of the three dependencies to ITEM_102.  The same would be for ITEM_101, ITEM_75 would be somewhere above it and there would be a line connecting it.

In the real world this tree represents a hierarchy of scheduling jobs.  We have a very extensive workload automation hierarchy in `Autosys` and I have heard that its front end utility has something like this tree visual representation, however, for some reason, that utility has been disabled by admins.  My business users want to see this hierarchy in an easy-to-consume format.

I was hoping that I won't have to program something like this from scratch because it seems like quite a common reporting requirement and the input data is simply formatted.  My question is:  is there a FOSS tool that takes standardized data input and produces such a hierarchical tree?

Thanks

Comment: Trees are fun. Don't miss out on this clear opportunity to write one yourself.

Comment: i agree, i love trees.  i'm a data tree hugger.  as much as i would love to write a tool like that myself, it wouldn't feel right to reinvent the wheel.  the answer below seems to be exactly what i need

Comment: Can't you get the admins to enable the utility?

Comment: dude, the bureaucracy is huge.  they will find every excuse possible.  http://www.graphviz.org/ will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

```
digraph {
    ITEM_101 -> ITEM_75
    ITEM_202 -> ITEM_77
}

dot input.dot -Tpng > image.png
```